# How to implement non standard relations in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a front-end application to display data from legacy database.

Unfortunately, the parent-child relationship cannot be implemented through a simple `Child.FK=Parent.PK`, conventionally supported by the has_many/belongs_to model clauses.

How can I define a specific relation condition for my relation, looking like:

```
Child.ITEM_NO = Parent.ITEM_NO and Child.INVENTORY = Parent.INVENTORY and (Child.ACCESS_MASK & Parent.ACCESS_MASK) ?
```

Comment: Through associations I don't think you can.  I think you'd have to define methods that returned the parent/children.

When you say it can't be implemented that way do you mean that it's not currently and you can't change it?

Comment: I can't modify the data model of legacy application to define simple PK/FK relations, so I apparently can't use the Rails has_many/belongs_to feature. But if it is possible to override the intrinsic join expression. What I did till now is implementing a function in the Parent model to return the list of Children.